# Split DNS for entire zone

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2019

I have my company.com domain's DNS servers hosted with Office 365, where all the Exchange/Skype records are set, but I also added the custom @/www A records for the public website.

Now I am setting a Windows Server 2019 Active Directory for the same company.com domain (I want to later synchronize it to the Office 365/Azure AD tenant).

My problem is that within the AD domain, www.company.com won't resolve. I could add the A record manually in the DNS configuration, but I am looking for a way to tell Windows that anything *.company.com that it cannot resolve should be checked against the external authoritative server (Office 365). Is there a way to setup once and forget about it?

Thanks,

Luis

Comment: `I am looking for a way to tell Windows that anything *.company.com that it cannot resolve should be checked against the external authoritative server (Office 365).` - This can't be done with Windows Server DNS

Answer (score 4):

Use for Active Directory subdomain corp.company.com

Comment: Would that require users requiring luis@corp.company.com to sign in to local AD resources, and luis@company.com to sign in to Office 365?

Comment: Connect AD to Office 365 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4wbyAo2-sA